# What causes a "This computer has more CPUs than allowed by the license" message?

Tags: 2011

I am getting following error while browsing my Tridion site.

> This computer has more CPUs than allowed by the license.
>
> Unable to Initialize TDSE object.

Can some tell what exactly the issue is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the error message is self-explanatory. You are trying to run Tridion in a server with more CPUs (it counts the cores, so 2 dual core processors would mean "4 CPUs") than allowed by your license.

Check your server CPUs (and cores) and the license file. There should be some xml attributes like `license-type="server_cpu_count` and the `usage-limit="4"`

Comment: Please note hyperthreading is also counted by the license check, so a dual core CPU with hyperthreading is counted as 4 (2 cores + 2 threads per core)

Answer (score 6):

The machine that you are running the cms on has got more CPUs than allowed in your licence.  You'll either need to reduce the number of CPUs used on the machine or contact SDL Tridion support to issue a new licence.

**Edit: to add a little more:**

The `TDSE` is Tridion's core 'engine' - this can't initialize because the licence isn't valid.

I hope this explains the full extent of the error message :)

Comment: *[snip]reduce the number of CPUs used on the machine[/snip]*, so they need remove (possibly desolder) a CPU from the motherboard right? ;o)

Comment: Eheh, that would be one way :) Contact customer support, I'd say, or change your VM settings if possible

Comment: @BartKoopman - no one has physical cpus anymore - get with the times dude!